# flyway commandline tool - what option to re-execute failed DDL?

Tags: java, oracle, flyway, ora-00955

I successfully ran v1 migration with a create table DDL. I copied same to v2 file and ran - got the expected validation error message:

> Migrating to version 1.0.002
>       com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Error executing statement
>       at line 1: create table people(id number(10) primary key, name varchar2(301))
>       Caused by java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by a
>       n existing object
>       MigrationException: Migration to version 1.0.002 failed! Please restore backups
>       and roll back database and code

I corrected the v2 file and ran flyway migrate again. Giving back the error message

> Current schema version: 1.0.002
>       MigrationException: Migration to version 1.0.002 failed! Please restore backups
>       and roll back database and code

I am not in a stage where a database backup is taken - simple trying to execute a fixed DDL. I don't currently see a solution short of flyway clean. Why cannot flyway try to execute FAILED versions again (if the checksum has changed)? Or shouldn't there be a flyway rollback command?

I know I can very well modify the code to make it that way, but was there any reason why you chose it to behave this way?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with simply reexecuting is that **some changes might already have been applied**, which will cause the migration to **fail**.

There are two solutions to this:

- Use a database that supports **DDL transactions** such as PostgreSQL, SQLServer or DB2
- Perform a **manual cleanup** of the modified structures and the metadata table before reapplying